# How to calculate milestones in servicenow

Tags: c#, .net, servicenow

I am working on [servicenow](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Creating_Project_Tasks#Creating_Milestones) - Project task [pm_project_task]

I am getting a list of tasks for a project using `pm_project_task` service url. This doesn't have the field such as `Milestone`.

How to find the milestone for a project task ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Milestones* are *Baselines* within ServiceNow I believe. Take a look at the `planned_task_baseline` and `planned_task_baseline_item` tables. These should have details about any baselines.

It may help a bit to take a look at the `Create Baseline` *UI Action* that is on the `pm_project` table and follow the code back to see how they are created.

A good reference for all of the things installed by the Project module is at http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Installed_with_Project_Management

Comment: How to proceed?. What is the field name to check with these tables for finding milestone for a project task.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by giving

```
duration = "1970-01-01 00:00:00" // -- > record is milestone
```

in filtering the records. `1970-01-01` is the default date.

I also used the `planned_task` table